# draw UML like diagram to represent math algorithm

Tags: uml

Suppose I have math algorithm e.g.

```
A = B + C
C = D + E
F = B + D
```

I would like to draw a diagram to represent it and the flow of the algorithm i.e. people know how the value of A calculate. Is there tool or the name of UML diagram that I can take a look?

Comment: IMHO, A = B + C is already a very good depiction of an algorithm... But of course, there are no lines to depict the flow. Why don't you just add them, why do you need some over standardized thing like UML? Draw some circles around "C" connect them with "D + E" ... done ;)

Comment: But when the number of equals are getting more and more. It is hard to know say if the value of B is changed, which fields are changed as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a [Dataflow Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram)?

Something like this:

[image: dataflow diagram example]

It's not part of UML, but can be a very useful way to show computation.

hth.

Answer (score 2):

There is an proposal to supplement UML diagrams by the diagrams called [KOPENOGRAM](http://www.kopenogram.org). Which rather on data flow focus on algorithmical structure, conditions, loops, etc. As this is an proposal, limited specific tools exist to generate or draw kopenograms from source code (AFAIK there are Java plugins for BlueJ or NetBeans). However, Excel or any spreadsheet app might be used to make table and borders.

Your example will look like:

[image]

No dependency is shown on operations as in previous example, as this is task rather for compiler.

Answer (score 1):

UML diagrams are either about static structure (classes/components/packages) or interaction *between entities* (activity/sequence diagrams/state machines).

Algorithms or algorithm design are not covered by UML (very much like any other type of concrete method specification).

Comment: so do you know if there is any diagram suited for this purpose?